# How to store before and after decimal value in 2 different column

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench, sql-query-store

```
Name    Gender  Amount
Ram male    20.56
Bhavna  female  78.2
darshan male    12.02
Avni    female  50.366
```

I want to divide the Amount Column in 2 parts where one Column includes the before decimal value (i.e 20.56=20) And Second column includes after decimal value (i.e 20.56=56)...

Comment: Don't.  Just don't.  Store the number, and let your *queries* differentiate between the whole and decimal parts of the number.

Comment: Use Floor function. But as @paulsm4 says, don't. Create a view if you really don't want to define it in queries.

Answer (score 1):

-- check this query

```
select amount, decode (pos,0,amount,substr(amount,1,pos-1)) as before_decimal , 
       decode(pos,0,0,substr(amount,pos+1,length(amount))) as after_decimal 
  from (
         select instr((substr(amount,1,length(amount))),'.') as pos,amount 
         from  table_name
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can get numbers using `FORMAT`:**

```
FORMAT(your_number,xxxxx) --you can choose xxxxx whatever you want
```

usage: `FORMAT (N, D)`

You can look how to use it : https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-format-function.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get your expected output like,

Amount is : 20.56

To get '20' as a output we can use this query

```
SELECT FLOOR(20.56) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

& To get exact '56' as a output we can use this query

```
SELECT FLOOR((20.56 - FLOOR(20.56))*100) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them in separate columns, you can use arithmetic functions:

```
select t.*, floor(val) as col_left, floor(val * 100) % 100 as col_right
from (select 20.56 as val) t
```